# Removing prefixes of variable lengths

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Below is a snapshot list of part numbers I've exported out of our ERP system.  The full list is thousands of parts long:

```
.121CZ1000
.015DC0036
..020DF0003
..030MD0021
..040NA0009
..010DB0171
...306AD0002
.075MC0161
..030MD0021
...321FC0001
.092DM0069
..120BZ0003
..120DZ0004
..120DZ0008
..123DZ0011
..128DZ0003
..134CZ0004
..139CZ0007
..156CZ0002
..165DZ0005
..166CZ0009
..174CZ0003
```

The BOM report I used to export has inserted `.`s to indicate the various levels within the BOM.  I need to use these part numbers in formulas, such as VLOOKUP or MATCH, so I need to have the `.`s removed.  I need a dynamic program that adjusts as the quantity of `.`s varies from row to row.

Answer (score 2):

Though not a VBA solution it appears that a formula such as:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",)
```

(copied down to suit) was all that was required.

Comment: + 1 For a non vba solution :)